# My wireless speed is very slow but my wired speed is normal

Tags: wireless-networking, router, internet-connection, wired

I have several laptops in the house, plus a desktop that has wired internet. (The laptops are wireless) The desktop's internet speed is normal, but on the laptops really sluggish. It can barely load a webpage. The laptops are in different places around the house, but they are all slow so I don't think it has to do with how far away they are from the router (ASUS DSL - N13).

Any clues on what it might be?

Answer (score 4):

Some standard things to try:

- Try a different channel.  And if everyone stuck to channels 1, 6, and 11, the world would be a better place.  There are network-scanning tools like [inSSIDer](http://www.metageek.net/products/inssider/) that help you visualize which channels are most busy where you are.
- Try disabling wide (40MHz) channels.  If you're in an area where you can barely find a single 20MHz-wide channel that's free enough to use, then trying to use a double-wide channel is probably just going to make you run into more interference.
- Try disabling other sources of 2.4GHz interference around you, such as Bluetooth, Wii Remotes, wireless speakers (including subwoofers), wireless webcams/security cams, wireless room-to-room A/V senders, cordless phones (some labeled 5.8GHz actually use 2.4GHz as well), microwave ovens, etc. etc.
- Re-enable the B and G rates if you previously disabled them. Even N gear uses B and G rates for best performance at range, so it's a bad idea to disable those rates.

Comment: I am ignorant of "if everyone stuck to channels 1, 6, and 11, the world would be a better place" -- please clarify.

Comment: Channels other than 1, 6, and 11 spill over onto 1, 6, and 11. So if you use, say, channel 4, you'll likely harm channel 1 as much as if you were using channel 1 *and* you'll harm channel 6 as much as if you were using channel 6.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard The 2.4GHz Wi-Fi channels each overlap several nearby channels. 1, 6, and 11 are far enough apart that they don't overlap each other. So if you only have 3 networks in range of each other they should be on 1, 6, and 11. If you have a fourth network in range it's better to re-use one of 1, 6, or 11, because same-channel interferers are dealt with more efficiently by the 802.11 protocol than partially-overlapping-channel interferers.

Comment: I would also suggest plugging the laptops in via Ethernet just to confirm the issue is your WiFi and not the laptops themselves; or if you don't have issues on those laptops on other wireless networks, you can rule out the wireless adapters on your devices.